# Cannot find horizontal tangent of the curve

Tags: derivatives

Does the curve represented by the equation $y= \cos x + 5x$  have any horizontal tangent?

I calculated $y\prime=0$ and i got $\sin x=5$ which is false  so what should  i do ?

Here is what i did :
$$
y = \cos x +5x,\\
y\prime=-\sin x +5
$$
I have 
$$
y\prime = 0 \implies -\sin x + 5 = 0\implies \sin x = 5
$$

Comment: So no horizontal tangent exists

Comment: the slope of $y = 5x + \cos x$ is between $4$ and $6.$

Comment: @abel how did u find  him ?

Comment: y'=0 gave you no solutions so there are no horizontal tangents @Ali Zgheib

Comment: $y'=-\sin(x)+5$..Recall $-1 \le -\sin(x) \le 1$. So $-1+5 \le y' \le 1+5$